# YUI3 Tabview How to determine the label of selected tab

Tags: yui, yui3, tabview

I need a [YUI3 tabview](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/tabview/#from-js) like

```
<div id="demo"></div>
<script>
YUI().use('tabview', function(Y) {
    var tabview = new Y.TabView({
        children: [{
            label: 'foo',
            content: '<p>foo content</p>'
        }, {
            label: 'bar',
            content: '<p>bar content</p>'
        }, {
            label: 'baz',
            content: '<p>baz content</p>'
       }]
    });
    tabview.render('#demo');
});
</script>
```

Now need a event handler which will be of following specification

1. It will be fired when user will click on tab something like "selectedTabChanged"
2. Inside the handler will determine the label of the "SelectedTab"

Answer (score 4):

Just add this below `tabview.render('#demo');`

```
tabview.on('selectionChange', function (e) {
    alert('Changing tab from "' + e.prevVal.get('label') + '" to "' + e.newVal.get('label') + '"');
}
```

Comment: The `selectionChange` event is mentioned in high-level docs, but it's missing from the API documentation: http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/TabView.html  Did you find it anywhere, or just dig in the source to find that the `label` property is available?

Comment: @ches. This was definitely a while ago.  But knowing myself, I almost surely dug into source code to get the extra info.  Fortunately YUI3 source is relatively readable.